# SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB shell version v4.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-12-05T20:42:40.108+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: Solution that worked for me is:

Opened the Task Manager (ctrl + shift + esc) -> Services tab and there was a MongoDB row with the status stopped. Then I right-clicked and clicked start and everything worked perfectly :).

Comment: The solution that worked for me is:

Opened the Task Manager (ctrl + shift + esc) -> Services tab and there was a MongoDB row with the status stopped. Then I right-clicked and clicked start and everything worked perfectly :).